# Added/Posted contacts not showing up in google contact list?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-plus, google-contacts-api

I am using Google APIs to perform various operations on my contacts. I wanted to add a contact to my contact list for this I used:

**POST:**

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?alt=json&max-results=500&v=3.0
```

**With the header**

```
    Authorization: Bearer "access_token"
    Content-Type: application/json
    data:{title: "BATMAN", phonenumber: "3333", email:"tdk@gmail.com"}
```

The get the response alright:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
```

This response was recorded by both Google OAuth 2.0 playground as well as Postman.

However when I wish to fetch the contact it is nowhere to be found. To fetch I my request is:

**GET:**

```
    https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?alt=json&max-results=500&v=3.0
```

**With the header**

```
    Authorization: Bearer "access_token"
```

I get all contacts but the one just created. Would like to know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What happens if you add the contact to a contact group, and retrieve that groups contacts? You might need to [add them to the main contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246570/add-contacts-to-google-contacts-main-contacts-list-not-hidden)

Comment: try people API it's easier contact API require XML not json iir